# LUIS AI dosn't return builtin entities like name

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have implemented a bot with luis ai.
One of the entites I use is the builtin.personName. If I test it online on the webpage, it returns the name correctly as entity.
If i use it in my bot, the entity personaName will be not returned.
There is the DateTimeV2 Entity and all of my own implemented... but not the personName.

Someone with the same issue or some ideas how to fix it?

BR

Comment: Did you train your model? In LUIS portal, are you testing local version or published version?

Comment: I have trained it, it is also published in the newest version.

As example a test online with "Steve will buy a apple on friday" results in Steve = Name, Apple = Fruit, Friday = DateTimeV2. But in my bot i only receive Fruit and DateTime

Comment: Hmm, I have tested another implementation today and now it works... that is strange...